# Как обновить часть данных на странице без обновления всей страницы

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Доброго времени суток!

У меня простой вопрос: можно ли в MVC проекте вернуть из контроллера данные в представление без обновления страницы представления???

Например, есть модальное окно, внутри которого форма. Данные с этой формы посылаются в контроллер, а затем, контроллер должен вернуть результат, который будет использован дальше в том же самом модальном окне. Возможен ли такой вариант и как это реализовать?

Comment: используйте ajax

Comment: @DreamChild, можно рабочий пример, пожалуйста.

Comment: боюсь у меня нет времени. Погуглите, это просто

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать поддержку [ajax](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX), имеющуюся в ASP-MVC. Это то, что предлагают в одном из ответов на этот вопрос сделать с помощью вызова  `@using(Ajax.BeginForm(...))`. С помощью этого метода можно создавать формы, данные которых будут обновляться без перезагрузки всей страницы. Чтобы использовать этот подход вам придется разобраться в деталях его использования, поищите информацию по запросу *"ненавязчивый ajax в ASP-MVC"*.

Вот [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/433198/%D0%98%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-ajax-beginform-%D0%B2-asp-net-mvc), в котором используется `Ajax.BeginForm()`.

Кроме того вы можете решить задачу с помощью функции [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) из jQuery.

Допустим вы хотите просто обновить информацию о товаре на странице. В методе контроллера вы вместо View должны вернуть данные в виде **json**:

```
    public class ProductController
    {
        public JsonResult GetProduct(long productId)
        {
            var product = product.GetProduct(productId)
            return Json(product, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); // возвращаем json
        }
    }
```

Теперь вы можете обратиться к этому методу с помощью jquery-метода [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), примерно вот так:

```
$('#updateProductButton').click(function () {
    var productId = $('#productId').val()
    var url = "/Product/GetProduct/" + productId;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (product) {
            // здесь в переменной product прийдет 
            // товар в виде json-объекта, и вы можете обновить
            // информацию на странице, используя эти данные              
        },
    }); 
 });
```

Для POST-запроса подход аналогичный, но вам надо будет написать `method: 'POST'` вместо `method: 'GET'`, и добавить параметр `data`, в который надо поместить данные для отправки на сервер.

То есть, если коротко, сценарий такой:

1. Вы создаете на сервере в контроллерах методы, возвращающие данные в формате **json**. Это более менее простая часть.
2. Вы вызываете эти методы из js с помощью метода [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Это будет посложнее, если у вас пока нет такого опыта, но здесь документация по **jquery** и **Google**  в помощь.

Comment: спасибо вам за подробный ответ!)))

Comment: @cat_woman пожалуйста ))

Answer (score 2):

Очень просто. Используем JQuery:

```
// собираем данные из формы в объект data
var data = {
    name: $('#name').val(),
    phone:$('#phone').val()
    //...
};

//и отправляем серверу в $_POST
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url:  '/<controller>/<action>',// заменить на Ваши значения
    data: {'data': JSON.stringify(data)},// придет  в виде строки - надо
                                         // будет преобразовать в массив
                                         // с помощью
                                         // json_decode($_POST["data"], true); (PHP)
    success: function(result){
        // что-то делаем с result, который контроллер
        // посылает в виде текста с помощью echo <Ваша переменная>; (PHP)
    }
});
```

Comment: Блин, только сейчас увидел, что используется `asp.net`)) ну, значит, там должны быть свои функции работы со структурой `POST`, `JSON`-форматом и отправки `echo`)

Answer (score 1):

C формой можно так поступить:

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm(...))
```