# Использование Ajax.BeginForm для обновления части страницы

Tags: html, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Нужно, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку в форме обновилась часть страницы. Ответ (*partial view*) от контроллера должен быть помещен в `div`, который указан в `UpdateTargetId`.

Но почему-то этого не происходит: страница обновляется полностью, и я вижу только *partial view*.

**Index**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#time").text(new Date().toString());
    });    
</script>       
<h2>Index</h2>    
<div id="time"></div>    
@using (@Ajax.BeginForm("AjaxTest", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "myDiv" }))
{    
    <div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>    
    <button type="submit" >Ajax request</button>    
}
```

**Контроллер**:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult AjaxTest()
    {
        return PartialView("DateInfo");
    }
}
```

**DateInfo.cshtml**:

```
<div>Some data</div>
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: как Вы подключали "jquery-unobtrusive"?

Comment: @Bald56rus, нет, не знал что нужно его подключать. Это где-нибудь документировано?? Подключил и все заработало! Можете конвертировать в ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Убедитесь что ненавязчивый ajax включен в web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

Убедитесь, что к вашей странице подключена библиотека, реализующая ненавязчивый ajax, и подключена jquery (ненавязчивый ajax использует возможности jquery и без нее работать не будет):

```
<head>    
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js ")" type="text/java script"X/script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript "X/script>    
</head>
```

Если в вашем проекте нет библиотеки `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` установите соответствующий [nuget-пакет](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/).

Comment: Jquery был подключен, подключил jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js и заработало. А есть ли смысл добавлять в web.config UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled? Как и кем он будет использоваться?

Comment: Насколько мне известно без этого ключа в конфиге не должно заработать. Если работает и без него, то конечно не добавляйте. Но вообще проверьте - скорее всего он уже есть у вас в конфиге, кажется он по умолчанию выставляется при создании проекта.

Comment: вы правы он уже был добавлен, просто я в не тот конфиг посмотрел. Их, в проекте, оказывается два.

Answer (score 2):

вполне возможно что у вас не подключен "jquery-unobtrusive" [ссылка](http://professorweb.ru/my/ASP_NET/mvc/level6/6_8.php) установите соответствующий пакет при помощи nuget